# Session id creation for users who share same pc

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How does a server allot different session to users logging in from same browser on same pc?

Is the only way creating forceful login? For example if me and my friend share the same pc and browser to  access an e-commerce website they dont recognise different sessions unless we login.
my question is not about what happens when n users access,I know it creates thread but there is no way to track different sessions from same browser on same pc at a time,but how does it  work in private mode ?

Comment: "*if me and my friend share the same pc and browser to access an e-commerce website...*" How?

Comment: You can "share a PC" but use a different username to use it

Comment: Same browser, same pc; would work fine, just NOT at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

One installation of a browser can have only one session of webapp active. By this I mean to say that if a user is logged into a website, the new tabs, new windows of the same installation will have the same session till it timesout or logged out.

As an example try to login to `mail.google.com` from one tab of firefox and try to open `mail.google.com` on another tab or a new window. You should still see the same session

One last thing: as long as the sessions are different, it doesnot matter if it is in the same machine or different machine. As an example, you could login to `mail.google.com` with your userid. Your friend could still login to `mail.google.com` using chrome to his/her mail account

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say.I see few websites forcing users to login very unnecessarily.Is their sole purpose to is to track session of a user? For example I could login with different id in private browsing mode,how does this work from normal usage ?

Comment: I will try to be brief as this thread is already marked as duplicate. There could be different reasons for forcing login but it ends up with ad-revenue (read about CPI and CPC). It also helps in syndicating ads more contextually (based on the details user has entered during registration)